# my useeffect hook doesn't load API data and use that data to help me render data to screen quickly when the user presses the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-hooks

I am following a tutorial and trying to load my API with useffect so that it doesnt take lot of time to load the data when the user clicks the button but the useEffect seems to not do anything as even when the button is pressed it takes around 6 seconds to retrieve data, please look at my code.

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchMoviesHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    const random = Math.random();
    console.log(random);
    console.log("RUNNING HANDLER");
    try {
      setError(null);
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/films`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      const transformedMovies = data.results.map((movieData) => {
        return {
          id: movieData.episode_id,
          title: movieData.title,
          openingText: movieData.opening_crawl,
          releaseDate: movieData.release_date,
        };
      });
      setMovies(transformedMovies);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
    fetchMoviesHandler();
  }, [fetchMoviesHandler]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just tried loading that URL myself in my browser, and it took 15 seconds to load (measure with the Network tab in my browser's devtools). So any slowness here isn't down to you, it's a problem with the server you're requesting the data from. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robin, i ran the instructors code from github itself and the issue seems to still be there so i think you are right that the issue is with the server.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch data and then set to `setMovies`.

you can try

```
 useEffect(() => {
 if(movies.length <1){
 fetchMoviesHandler()
 }
 }, [movies]);
```